# Install Ubuntu alongside Windows with one USB flash drive

Tags: software-installation, windows, usb-drive

I want to install Ubuntu alongside my Windows installation. My laptop has no CD drive, and I have only one USB flash stick, which is 32GB. 
In all installation tutorials I've seen, it is highly recommended to save a recovery for Windows, just in case the installation causes problems.

How can I install Ubuntu from a flash drive, and also save a recovery of Windows, using only one USB flash drive?

Comment: It is very advanced to try to configure one flash drive for both Windows & Ubuntu repairs. Best to have full backup of Windows and a repair flash drive or live installer for repairs that are for current versions of every operating system you have installed. Flash drives are now very inexpensive. Microcenter in USA has 32GB USB3 for $7.  I only suggest them as I live near a store and have purchased one just about every time I go to store as price is cheaper or drive larger or now USB3. I now have too many drives to keep track of. :)

Answer (score 0):

Although it pretty much never happens that the installation fails, the only way I could think of is making a recovery partition. I did a quick search for you and found [this](http://www.intowindows.com/how-to-create-dedicated-recovery-partition-of-windows-10/).